Finding next prime number lands in an execution error (time limit exceeded)
Does anyone have any idea on why the program may crash? The input is prime numbers, and you have to search the next one. If you input a non-prime, it stops. Thanks.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int nextprime (int);
bool primality (int);

int main () {
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    bool prime = primality(a);
    while (prime) {
        cout << nextprime(a) << endl;
        cin >> a;
        prime = primality(a);
    }
    
}
int nextprime (int x) {

    ++x;
    if (x % 2 == 0 and x != 2) ++x;
    bool prime = primality(x);
    while (not prime) {
        x = x + 2;  
        prime = primality (x);
    }
    return x;
    
}

bool primality (int x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0 and x != 2) return false;
    for (int number = 3; number*number <= x; number = number + 2) {
        if (x % number == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

Everything works for me, even big prime numbers. I don't know what makes it fail. It works for everything I input, but the "code judge" still gives execution error

Your code (algorithm) is simply too slow. Look up sieve of Erathostene for a faster algorithm

You're doing a lot more work than necessary.  You don't need to do trial division with all the odd numbers, just the primes.

Also note that you do not need to check any factors after sqrt(number_to_check).  If you have not found a divisor by then, you are not going to.

Do you understand what "time limit exceeded" means?  You seem to be thinking it means "crash", but that is not the case.  You are simply being told your program could be faster.

Did you really get "time limit exceeded"? Which error message did you get? You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Brute force solutions re typically not worth trying on judging sites. The sites are usually looking for some neat math trick you can use to dramatically reduce the amount of work required. This problem may work with a prime number sieve, but there's a chance you'll need to go with something even sneakier.

@NathanOliver the condition number*number <= x covers that case.  Might be faster to do a single sqrt though if you're looping a lot.

You should always report your findings from what happened when you used your debugger.

The judging site may expect something faster like the sieve of Pritchard for generating prime factors or maybe just the wheel method for primes <32. You can easily gain a 30% speed up by skipping odd numbers that divide by 3 (by alternating the increment between 2 and 4).

@MarkRansom I've found lifting that out of the loop like selbie does in there answer is a net win.  The amount of times you do the multiplication in larger primes far outweighs the call to sqrt.

Basically, you've implemented a brute-force approach (checking every odd integral value) for checking if a value is prime (in primality()) and for finding a next prime (in nextprime()).   Brute force approaches tend to be slow (their virtue is that they cannot give incorrect results, unless a numerical error such as overflow occurs).    Try working out a faster algorithm (in both cases).   Sieve of Eratosthene (as suggested by Jeffrey) is a much faster approach for finding primes than your brute force approach, and can be adapted for your purpose).

One slight speed improvement.
Change this:
for (int number = 3; number*number <= x; number = number + 2) {
    if (x % number == 0) return false;
}

To this:
const int sqrtX = (int)(std::sqrt(x) + 1); // some implementations of sqrt have rounding issues even within the 32-bit range. So +1 isn't a bad idea
for (int number = 3; number <= sqrtX; number = number + 2) {
    if (x % number == 0) return false;
}

It trades off multiplying number*number on each iteration to just comparing number against the square root of x, which is only computed once.  Make sure to #include <cmath> so you get the sqrt function.
If you don't want to code Sieve of Eratosthenes, you can take advantage of the fact that you can skip not just odd numbers, but multiples of 3 and 5 too.  You can reference my faster than average isPrime function on my github: https://github.com/jselbie/isprime/blob/master/isprime.cpp
Basically, in your loop, you're doing a mod check on exactly half the numbers leading up to sqrt(x).  You can get that down to 8 mod checks per jump of +30 on number. That will reduce the runtime of your original algorithm down by about half again.
Another hint that may or may not be applicable. If you know all the prime numbers between 2..N (where N is prime).  Let's call this set P.   Then as you are evaluating the possible candidates for "next prime after N", you only need to do mod tests using the numbers in P.
